# Delete method just appends a question mark to the current URL and doesn't delete the blogpost

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a little blog app with Node and Express. When I'm on a blogpost and click the submit button, it does nothing except that it adds a ? into the link which you can see here:
http://prntscr.com/gizmvu

**I tripple checked my code and I can't find a solution. 
Here is my delete route:**

```
//DELETE ROUTE
app.delete("/blogs/:id", function(req, res){
    res.send("you have reached DELETE ROUTE");
});
```

**And here is the actual form:**

```
<form action="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>?_method=DELETE" method"POST">
    <button class="ui red basic button">Delete</button>
</form>
```

**I also made sure to include `app.use(methodOverride("_method"));`in my file.**

I also double checked that I saved all files and restarted the server. Mongodb server also running. I can't get it to work. I also have a put method in my code and this is working fine (so the methodOverride should work).

The expected behaviour should be:

Just show me a page with text "You have reachted DELETE ROUTE" as you can see in my delete route. But instead I stay on the same site and it just appends ? mark.

Comment: Is the express router getting called?

Comment: Yes it's getting called with that line `<form action="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>?_method=DELETE" method"POST">` so express knows that's a DELETE method and should call the `app.delete()` route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I missed the `=` sign in the form. I changed from `method "POST"`to `method="POST"`now it's working perfectly. Such a stupid mistake.